# Mapping though 2 dimensional array and format 2 index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

my starting array looks like this.

```
prices: [
 [date,price],
 [date,price]
...
]
```

so i'm trying to return both of the date and the price in the same array structure by formatting the data but i'm having issue to return both of them. I've tried to do something like

```
return this.prices.map(a => moment(a[0]).format("h:mm:ss a") && this.roundToDecimal(a[1))
```

Weirdly, it doesn't return both of them as it should be in my mind.

I would like to understand if How I have proceeded was right or is there any way to manipulate the data .

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you want to return an array `[moment..., this.roundTo...]` rather than using the `&&` binary operator, which returns the first truthy operand.

Comment: @ggorlen thank you!!! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return an array inside your map callback function, something like:

```
return this.prices.map(a => [
    moment(a[0]).format("h:mm:ss a"), 
    this.roundToDecimal(a[1])
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this? If so, the difference is returnng an array literal inside your map function.

```js
var prices = [
    ["2020-05-22T13:30:17-05:00", 3.69],
    ["2020-05-22T14:30:17-05:00", 2.89]
];

function roundToDecimal(x) { return Math.round(x * 100) / 100; }

var mapped = prices.map(a => [
    moment(a[0]).format("h:mm:ss a"),
    roundToDecimal(a[1])
]);

document.write(JSON.stringify(mapped));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would like to thank you. You did more than I asked. I wish I had 15 reputations so I could upvote you.